# ggplot Stacked Area Plot, How To Invert Position of Areas?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph similar to this one:
[image: stacked area]

To achieve this I am using the following code:

```
ggplot(eth_txs2, aes(x=date))+
  geom_area(aes(y=eth_percent, group = 1), color = "blue", fill = "blue")+
  geom_area(aes(y=opt_percent, group = 1), color = "red", fill = "red")+
  geom_area(aes(y=arb_percent, group = 1), color = "lightblue", fill = "lightblue")
```

Using this dataset: [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQxBV.png)

But the result looks like this: [image: result]

How can I make it look similar to the first picture? I need cover the grey area to make the graph occupy 100% of the chart.

Comment: hi welcome to SO. The title of the question and the question asked don't line up. *" I need cover the grey area to make the graph occupy 100% of the chart."* Do you mean you want your graph's x-axis to only show the 2021 till now area as is shown in the first graph

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~date, ~eth_percent, ~opt_percent, ~arb_percent,
  1, 80, 10, 0,
  2, 85, 2, 3,
  3, 98, 1, 1,
  4, 98, 1, 1,
  5, 95, 3, 2,
)

other_data <-
  data |>
  pivot_longer(-date) |>
  group_by(date) |>
  summarise(
    name = "other",
    value = 100 - sum(value)
  )
other_data
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>    date name  value
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 other    10
#> 2     2 other    10
#> 3     3 other     0
#> 4     4 other     0
#> 5     5 other     0

data |>
  pivot_longer(-date) |>
  full_join(other_data) |>
  ggplot(aes(date, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_area()
#> Joining, by = c("date", "name", "value")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>